# Why does function call on array item produce "not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, callback

This code works:

```
function forEach (list, callback) {
  for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    callback.call(list[n], n);
  }
}
```

The following does not:

```
function forEach (list, callback) {
  for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    list[n].callback(n);  // Uncaught TypeError: 
                          //   list[n].callback is not a function
  }
}
```

Note: In each case, `callback` is passed an anonymous function with one argument, like so:

```
forEach(array, function(index) {
  // log to console...
});
```

Comment: Because `list[n]` is not an object with a `callback` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript understands the statement

```
list[n].callback(n);
```

as meaning

- Fetch `list[n]`
- Fetch the property named "callback" of the object fetched
- Invoke that value as a function, passing `n`

Because your list does not contain objects that have a property named "callback", you get that error.

The working code posted in your question is the correct way to invoke the callback function, as you've noticed. The value of the `callback` parameter is the function to be invoked, so that code uses `.call()` to invoke the function with the value of `list[n]` as the value to be used for `this`.

It would be a **really terrible idea** to write code like this, but it would work (except for the possible problems that are the reason for it being a **terrible idea**):

```
function forEach (list, callback) {
  for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    list[n].callback = callback; // <-- TERRIBLE IDEA - DO NOT DO
    list[n].callback(n);
  }
}
```

Again, **do not do this** because of the significant likelihood of introducing regrettable bugs, but it would work because it explicitly gives each object in the list a value for a property named "callback".

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is because list is an array and using . operator with list signifies that callback is an object but, callback is passed as a parameter.

callback.call() is right because the call method exists on all functions in Javascript. It allows you to call the functions.